# load a file to generate class from a specified annotation parameter

Tags: android, annotations, code-generation

I'd like to write something like

```
@MyAnnotation("pathToLocalFile")
public class MyClass(){...}
```

But it looks like the path is found in the annotation process project not in the project I use the annotation. If anybody has any idea...
For the record, the project follows the structure described on this page http://brianattwell.com/android-annotation-processing-pojo-string-generator/ 
So I have those 3 projects:

- API which describes the annotation
- compiler which describes the processor
- app which used all of this and where i want to specify a local json file
  Done on Android studio